# null value in column "balance" violates not-null constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to update balance from another table, with sum function but im getting this error:

> null value in column "balance" violates not-null constraint

Any suggestion how can i check to not update null values or to change query so that works?

This is my query:

```
update apt_profile 
set payment_currency_code ='CC',
balance =  (select sum(open_amount_total) from fnt_pym_profile where fnt_pym_profile.profile_id =apt_profile.id and status ='OPEN')
where payment_currency_code ='DD';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-coalesce/).

```
update apt_profile 
set payment_currency_code ='CC',
balance = coalesce(select sum(open_amount_total) from fnt_pym_profile where fnt_pym_profile.profile_id =apt_profile.id and status ='OPEN'), 0)
where payment_currency_code ='DD';
```

This should 0 the balance.

Answer (score 0):

OR use ISNULL:

```
update apt_profile
set payment_currency_code ='CC',
balance =  ISNULL(select sum(open_amount_total) from fnt_pym_profile where fnt_pym_profile.profile_id =apt_profile.id and status ='OPEN'), 0)
where payment_currency_code ='DD';
```

Comment: where is the is null ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Sorry, I'd lost isnull.